what is the appropriate risk of bias assessment tool for within-subject experimental designs?
I'm working on a systematic review in which the vast majority of the included studies are using a within subject design, where all of the subject perform one or more tasks in one condition, and then perform it again under a different condition.
I don't believe the RoB2 or ROBINS would be appropriate, as there is only a single group involved, and no follow up.
So, what could i use to assess the risk of bias of the included studies? is there a validated tool?

To the best of my knowledge, a good tool doesn't exist. The closest in to use to ROBINS-I to generate a theoretical RCT and then work your way through the biases that can be introduced due to the study design and conduct of the study. I expect it will be a lot of time spent to come to the conclusion that these studies are a high risk of bias (no blinding, no independent comparison group, etc.).
